# To + infinitive vs. To + gerund

Tags: gerunds, infinitives, gerund-vs-infinitive, predicate-frames

In one of the grammar books I study I found a following example:

**In my previous job I was confined to doing only one thing**.

I'd say that **confined to do** is the correct way to say it. I always thought that we can never use **to + gerund**, or can we? And if so, then what is the rule?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: *She was assigned to looking after the children. He was restricted to driving only in daylight*. There's no particular principle involving the *preposition* (not "infinitive marker") ***to*** in the context of gerunds. You just use that preposition if it's the right one to go with the "main" verb *(**confined to, assigned to, restricted to**)*.

Comment: ...but note that whereas idiomatically you're normally ***confined, restricted*** or ***limited to doing** something*, you could also be ***constrained, instructed, ordered to do** it*. Rarely if ever the other way around.

Comment: The _to_ is not the infinitive marker, but rather a transitivizing preposition governed by the predicate (in this case, _be confined_), which requires _to_ when it's transitive. This predicate takes a gerund complement following the _to_, like several other predicates; and unlike still other predicates, which don't govern _to_ when they're transitive.